# disable abbreviation in Vim

Tags: vim

Anyone know how to disable specific abbreviation such as `:cabbr` in Vim

I know how to clear them all with `:cabclear`

But I can not find any doc for clear specific `:cabbr`

Also after I disable all the abbre, is there any way I can recover all the abbre? or restore some specific abbreviations

Comment: `:help :cunabbrev`

Comment: Why can't you just delete / comment out the original definition? Is this from a plugin (not many of those define abreviations, and they should allow you to opt out)?

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is `:cunabbrev`. Check the help files.

> Also after I disable all the abbre, is there any way I can recover all the abbre? or restore some specific abbreviations

No, at least not in the same session since you don't really "disable" but rather remove the abbreviations. To bring them back you need to reload your vimrc and plugin files.

Ideally, you should remove the undesired abbreviation at its source instead of removing it after it was created. In case you're unsure where it's coming from, you can check that with `:verbose`:

```
:verb ab unwanted-abbrev
```